# awk multiple row and printing results

Tags: awk, ksh

I would like to print some specific parts of a results with awk, after multiple pattern selection.

What I have is (filetest):

```
A    : 1
B    : 2
```

I expect to have:

```
1 - B : 2
```

So, only the result of the first row, then the whole second row. 
The dash was added by me.

I have this:

```
awk -F': ' '$1 ~ /A|B/ { printf "%s", $2 "-" }' filetest
```

Result:

```
1 -2 -
```

And I cannot get the full second row, without failing in showing just the result of the first one

```
awk -F': ' '$1 ~ /A|B/ { printf "%s", $2 "$1" }' filetest
```

Result:

```
1 -    A    2 -    B
```

Is there any way to print in the same line, exactly the column/row that I need with awk?
In my case `R1C2 - R2C1: R2C2`?

Thanks!

Comment: will you always have extra empty line between the records?or is that copy pasting issue?

Comment: Probably copy paste issue, yes. No space between the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are expecting:

```
awk -F: '/^A/{printf "%s -", $2}/^B/{print}' filetest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F: 'NR%2 {printf "%s - ", $2; next}1' filetest
1 - B : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
awk -F:  'NR%2==1{a=$2; } NR%2==0{print a " - " $0}' file
```

output

```
  1 - B : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with [@jas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830693/1745001) as it's clear, simple, and not coupled to your data values but just to show an alternative approach:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", (NR%2 ? $3 " - " : $0 ORS)}' file
1 - B    : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk

```
awk -F':' 'NR==1{s=$2;next}{FS="";s=s" - "$0;print s}' filetest
```